# Runnable not run

Tags: android, timer, handler, runnable

I am using Handler and Runnable to display time of media player. but my runnable don't run. my code is:

```
Handler timerHandler;

public Contstructor() {
        timerHandler = new Handler();
    }
```

I'm using:

```
Runnable sourceTimer = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            long totalDuration = source.getDuration();
            long currentDuration = source.getCurrentPosition();

            String remainDurationLabel = milliSecondsToTimer(totalDuration - currentDuration);
            Log.e(TAG, "source remain time is " + remainDurationLabel);

            timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
        }
    };
```

start the timer:

```
void sourcePlay() {
        source.start();
        timerHandler.postDelayed(sourceTimer, 0);
    }
```

I don't receive any error but not logging "source remain time is " in logcat.

What's the problem?

Comment: *What's the problem?*  either you never call `sourcePlay()` or you have some issues with your logcat perspective

Comment: I called it in other activity: `mAudios[i].sourcePlay();`

Comment: Can you post the complete source codes . The information given is not enough to figure out what's wrong eg `source.start()` when there is no `source` variable in your code.